# display a label with the result of a strategy.exit

Tags: pine-script

I have scripted a strategy that enters a position and exits when limit or stop targets are reached

```
strategy.entry("Long", true, 1, when = validLong, comment= "Long " + display)
strategy.exit("Exit Long", from_entry = "Long", limit = tradeTargetPrice, stop = tradeStopPrice, when=strategy.position_size > 0)
```

I would like to display on the chart a shape.labelup when the trade is exited with its result (win or loss), but for the life of me i can't figure out how.

Additionally, digging in the documentation i couldn't find a built-in variable that lets me access the current price (i can read of course open, close, high, low, volume, etc. but not the actual current price)

can anyone help me out please?
thanks!

Comment: The close price of last bar is "actual current price"

Comment: You can starts from this `plotshape(strategy.position_size[1] != strategy.position_size)`

Answer (score 0):

```
percentage = round(100 * ((close - strategy.position_avg_price[1])/strategy.position_avg_price[1]))
labelColor = iff(percentage>0,color.green,color.red)
if(strategy.closedtrades-strategy.closedtrades[1] > 0)
   label.new(bar_index, high+25,style=label.style_circle,text=tostring(percentage),color=labelColor)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lastTradeResult = strategy.closedtrades.profit_percent(strategy.closedtrades -1)
labelColor = lastTradeResult>0 ? color.green : color.red 
if(strategy.closedtrades > strategy.closedtrades[1])
    label.new(bar_index, high+25 , style=label.style_triangleup , text=str.tostring(lastTradeResult) , color=labelColor)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).